# How to compare list custom setting records with other list of lead?

Tags: apex, list, customsetting

How to compare list custom setting records with other list of lead?

```
//this list store the list of lead records
List<Lead> leaddetails=new List<Lead> leaddetails();

//This custom setting store the list user emails and names
List<Customsettingobj> USers= [Select Name,Email__c from Customsettingobj__c ];
```

How to compare whether lead owner email is in custom setting records or not?

I have tried multiple ways but not able to achieve

I have tried with the below Approch , somehow it is not working in all scenorios

```
List<Lead> leaddetails

List<Customsettingobj__c> USers= [Select Name,Email__c from Customsettingobj__c ];
system.debug('leaddetails1'+SLAUSers);

  for(lead l : leaddetails){
    for(Customsettingobj__c us:USers){
        if(l.owner.email==us.Email__c){
            l.Flag_c__c=true;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please include code what have you done so far.

Comment: updated the code which i have tried, check once

Answer (score 0):

Get your custom setting data, add that data to Emailset.

```
Set<String> EmailSet = new Set<String>();  
for (Customsettingobj__c rv : Customsettingobj__c.getAll().values()) {
   EmailSet.add(rv.Email__c);
 }
```

check that EmailSet contains lead owner email.If yes make flag is true

```
for(lead l : leaddetails){
  if(EmailSet.contains(l.owner.email){
     l.Flag_c__c=true;
  }}
```

No need to use soql queries for custom settings

Read about custom settings:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm